# Relationship oneToMany using hibernate and entitymanagerfactory java

Tags: java

I have a problem while building a OneToMany relationship between two entities. I have a user who can have multiple Properties.  I want to define this relationship and create tables in MySql however when I run it it gives me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at start.ApplicationStart.main(ApplicationStart.java:44)
and also there are 2 more columns in the user table in mysql "user_id" and city. Now what I defined so far in my code is: 
in class user I have the following fields:

```
 @Id
    private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //mapped by variable in class user
    private List<Properties> properties;
```

and in class Properties I have:

```
@Column(name = "city")
 private String city; 

 @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
 private String address;


 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="user_id")// , nullable=false
private User user;
```

I don't understand why I have the extra columns in the user table. Also I am using entity manager for both tables. Any hint would be great

Comment: You've designated the join column as "user_id" ... yet that column is not defined in either user or Properties ... did you mean to use another column name ?

Comment: I'm really not sure how this could be done, this is what I understood from examples on the internet where user_id didn't appear in neither of the classes. So a hint would be great because all I want is to define the one to many relationship. In other examples I saw there's no need for joincolumn so im stuck

Comment: Not sure if its required ...I always have the join column match the actual primary key of the table i'm joining ... in your case changing the key to user_id on the user, for example ... you may want to make the ManyToOne fetch lazy .. As this is a bidirectional mapping you should add an addProperties and removeProperties method on the User to keep the bidirectional in sync. And implementing equals and hash on the Properties so that it remains fixed throughout the entity state transitions ...